# Get index of numpy-array elements by comparing element-positions between arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

**Context**

I have the following example-arrays in `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

# All arrays in this example have the shape (15,)
# Note: All values > 0 are unqiue!
a         = np.array([8,5,4,-1,-1, 7,-1,-1,12,11,-1,-1,14,-1,-1])
reference = np.array([0,1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14])
lookup    = np.array([3,6,0,-2,-2,24,-2,-2,24,48,-2,-2,84,-2,-2])
```

My goal is to find the elements inside the `reference` in `a`, then get the index in `a` and use it to extract the corresponding elements in `lookup`.

Finding out the matching elements and their indices works with `np.flatnonzero( np.isin() )`.
I can also lookup the correspodning values:

```py
# Example how to find the index
np.flatnonzero( np.isin( reference, a) )
# -> array([ 4,  5,  7,  8, 11, 12, 14])

# Example how to find corresponding values:
lookup[ np.flatnonzero( np.isin( a, reference) ) ]
# -> array([ 3,  6,  0, 24, 24, 48, 84], dtype=int64)
```

**Problem**

I want to fill an array `z` with the values I looked up, following the reference.
This means, that e.g. the 8th element of `z` corresponds to the 8th element in the lookup-value for the 8th element in `reference` (= 8). This value would be 3 (`reference[8] -> a[0] because a==8 here -> lookup[0] -> 3`).

```py
z = np.zeros(reference.size)
z[np.flatnonzero(np.isin(reference, a))] = ? -> numpy-array of correctly ordered lookup_values
```

The expected outcome for `z` would be:

```py
z = [ 0  0  0  0  0  6  0  24  3  0  0 48 24 0  84]
```

I cannot get my head around this; I have to avoid `for-loops` due to performance reasons and would need a pure numpy-solution (best without `udfs`).

**How can I fill `z` according with the lookup-values at the correct position?**

*Note: As stated in the code above, all values `a > 0` are unique. Thus, there is no need to take care about the duplicated values for `a < 0`.*

Comment: @H.Doebler: Thanks for the hint. I tried to simplify the question and forgot to eliminate it entirely.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided what you expect to see in `z` in this example

Comment: @Randy: I updated the question accordingly

Comment: It seems to me that using `np.flatnonzero(np.isin(reference, a))` you look up which elements of `reference` are in `a`, but do not capture where in `a` they are. So why do you want to use `np.flatnonzero(np.isin(reference, a))` then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually had an enlightenment.

```py
# Initialize the result
# All non-indexed entries shall be 0
z = np.zeros(reference.size, dtype=np.int64)
```

Now evaluate which elements in `a` are relevant:

```py
mask = np.flatnonzero(np.isin(a, reference))

# Short note: If we know that any positive element of a is a number
# Which has to be in the reference, we can also shorten this to
# a simple boolean mask. This will be significantly faster to process.
mask = (a > 0)
```

Now the following trick: All values `a > 0` are unique. Additionally, their value corresponds to the position in `reference` (e.g. 8 in `a` shall correspond to the 8th position in `reference`. Thus, we can use the values as index themselves:

```py
z[ a[mask] ] = lookup[mask]
```

This results in the desired outcome:

```py
z = [ 0  0  0  0  0  6  0  24  3  0  0 48 24 0  84]
```

Answer (score 0):

You say that you 'have to avoid for-loops due to performance reasons', so I assume that your real-world datastructure `a` is going to be large (thousands or millions of elements?). Since `np.isin(reference, a)` performs a linear search in `a` for every element of `reference`, your runtime will be O(`len(reference) * len(a)`).

I would strongly suggest using a `dict` for `a`, allowing lookup in O(1) per element of `reference`, and loop in python using `for`. For sufficiently large `a` this will outperform the 'fast' linear search performed by `np.isin`.

Answer (score 0):

The most natural way I can think of is to just treat `a` and `lookup` as a dictionary:

```
In [82]: d = dict(zip(a, lookup))

In [83]: np.array([d.get(i, 0) for i in reference])
Out[83]: array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  6,  0, 24,  3,  0,  0, 48, 24,  0, 84])
```

This does have a bit of memory overhead but nothing crazy if `reference` isn't too large.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Actually, the values in reference are quite huge (1.000.000 entries) and there exist more arrays then `a`. The data is also passed as `np.array` to me and leaving the structure results in critical memory overhead. Thus, I am looking for a pure numpy solution.